# Plot without lines with Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I can't find a way to render my graph as separate points. I want each point to be rendered separately. In my case drawing a line between data points doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set strokeWidth to zero: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/2952)

```
new Dygraph(data, div, {
  drawPoints: true,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  pointSize: 5
});
```

Comment: Still a classic :-)

Comment: In R, it'd be `dygraphs::dyOptions(drawPoints = T, strokeWidth = 0, pointSize = 5)`